# Compare two rasters: if the same cells in both rasters are NA or only one raster is NA

Tags: r, cluster-computing, hpc, terra

I have several large rasters (.tif files) with the same geometry. I want to compare them to see if all rasters have values or NA in the same cells. And if a raster has values and the other does not, I would like to know which ones do not have values in the same cell. I submitted my R scripts to the HPC cluster but encounter some errors.

Here are my scripts

```
library(terra)

ForestBio1 <- rast("/lustre1/scratch/ForestClim_01.tif")
offset_new <- rast("/lustre1/scratch/meanT_offset_annual.tif")
macro2020 <- rast("/lustre1/scratch/CHELSA_EUForest_1981-2010_25m_bio1.tif")
macro2100 <- rast("/lustre1/scratch/CHELSA_EUForest_ssp370_25m_bio1.tif")

#Make raster stack.
 r1 <- c(offset_new, ForestBio1)

## Method1: If you want to distinguish the "1" cases to know which year was NA, you can instead do
u1 <- is.na(r1) |> unique(as.raster=TRUE)
plot(u1)
cats(u1)[[1]]
freq(u1)
writeRaster(u1, filename = "/lustre1/scratch/distinguishNA_OffsetForestBio1.tif", overwrite=TRUE)
```

However, in Method1, I got this error from the HPC cluster:

```
> u1 <- is.na(r1) |> unique(as.raster=TRUE)
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) :      
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'unique': [is.na] interrupted
```

I also tried another way to get the NA patterns among two rasters:

```
## Method2: Get unique NA patterns
u1 <- is.na(r1) |>
  terra::aggregate(fun=unique, fact=1, na.rm=TRUE)  # Use unique to get unique NA patterns
  plot(u1)
  cats(u1)[[1]]
  freq(u1)
writeRaster(u1, filename = "/lustre1/scratch/distinguishNA_OffsetForestBio1.tif", overwrite=TRUE)
```

With Method2, I got this error:

```
Error: [aggregate] all values in argument 'fact' are 1, nothing to do
Execution halted
```

Here are some information about my input raster data:

```
> offset_new
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 161239, 132862, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 25, 25  (x, y)
extent      : 2634975, 5956525, 1385025, 5416000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs 
source      : meanT_offset_annual.tif 
name        : meanT_offset_annual 
min value   :              -5.661 
max value   :               7.752 

> ForestBio1
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 161239, 132862, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 25, 25  (x, y)
extent      : 2634975, 5956525, 1385025, 5416000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs 
source      : ForestClim_01.tif 
name        : ForestClim_01 

> macro2020
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 161239, 132862, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 25, 25  (x, y)
extent      : 2634975, 5956525, 1385025, 5416000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs 
source      : CHELSA_EUForest_1981-2010_25m_bio1.tif 
name        : CHELSA_bio1_1981-2010_V.2.1 
min value   :                        -4.3 
max value   :                        19.8 

> macro2100
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 161239, 132862, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 25, 25  (x, y)
extent      : 2634975, 5956525, 1385025, 5416000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs 
source      : CHELSA_EUForest_ssp370_25m_bio1.tif 
name        : mean 
min value   :  0.1 
max value   : 23.7
```

Does anyone have any clues why these error message occur on HPC clusters?

I am trying to check if all the rasters have values in the same cell and if the cell loacation of NA is also the same for all the rasters.